# My loop doesn't loop through the array properly

Tags: arrays, c, loops

A Fibonacci program that I wrote is not working correctly. This program should display the nth and nth series but this is what happened: the resulting output is:

```
1 8 13 21 34 55 1284926876 32762 -440528208 678 1285217672
```

Whereas it should be the 5th to 15th Fibonacci:

```
1 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
  int jbf, c, a, b, m, s;
  int hasil[100];
  printf("============================ \n");
  printf("| Program  Fiboonanci ");
  printf("| \n");
  printf("============================ \n");
  printf("enter number of rows : ");
  scanf("%d", &jbf);
  printf("starting from line: ");
  scanf("%d", &m);
  s = jbf + m;
  if (jbf > 0) {
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    printf("%d ", b);
    for (int i = 1; i < jbf; i++) {
      c = a + b;
      hasil[i] = c;
      a = b;
      b = c;
    }
    for (int i = m; i < s; i++) {
      printf("%d ", hasil[i]);
    }
  } else {
    printf("enter a value > 0");
  }
}
```

Comment: The first loop iterates to `jbf` this should be `s`

Comment: Tip: Variable names with some cohesion and meaning help us understand your code a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
scanf("%d", &jbf);

for ( int i = 1; i < jbf; i++) {

s = jbf + m;

for ( int i = m; i < s; i++) {
```

it looks to me that `s > jbf` so you also print values which were not calculated. I would also check for s>99, you have `int hasil[100];`, but the indexes in that field are `0..99` not `1..100`, but you index from `1`, which is fine as long as you remember that you allocated space for 100 `int` values, but you can use only 99 of them right now.